# Does uploading an app to itunes connect make it public?

Tags: app-store-connect

I would like to enable game center multiplayer in my game, and apparently to do so i need to upload my app into itunes connect. Does uploading an app to itunes connect make it public? Itunes connect asks me to add the app icon and things like that there, and i would not want to publish my game yet. I just want to try out multiplayer in my game

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, uploading and publishing are two different things. There is an extra publish switch in iTunes Connect. If you want to try the multiplayer you can even distribute your app to some specific email addresses only before you make it public.

Comment: If i press the submit for review, will it be published?

Comment: No, at the bottom of your app page you can define when to publish it (even when its submitted for review).

Please accept my answer if it helped you. Thanks!